# Is it good to save images in database with meteor?

Tags: javascript, angular, meteor, gridfs, collectionfs

I have images more than .5 millions and I am using meteor and angular for developing app. I have a doubt to save images on database because it could be slow the speed of project.

```
1-- where to store images in meteor angular app?

2-- I am using collection FS and grid FS for saving images.

3- what is the best practice to store images with meteor + angular app.
```

I can use s3 and cdn to store my images but it's really costly.
if any one have good suggestion, please help
thanks

Comment: too broad
Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I think this links may help you: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/ and https://atmospherejs.com/cfs/gridfs

Answer (score 0):

You DEFINITELY DO NOT want to store images in a database.  The best way to store images in on a file system like Amazon S3 and when new images are uploaded, store the link to the file and other appropriate metadata in the database.  Then, when you would like to access the file, simple call it using its link in the database.

Unfortunately there is no real way to get around the cost of storing large amounts of data these days.  On the plus side, it's way cheaper than it used to be...